# Quran App a surah view like uthmanic quran 15 line how to make it like quran for android app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a full Islamic app but I have an issue I want to make the surah view like the **"Quran for Android"** application I can make it in qcf font but it is too long way.
I found an image and database called ayahinfo_1260.db It helps to draw Canvas on the screen for highlight verses.
I want to use it in the Flutter app anyone have an idea how to make it :)

I tried it using qcf font and it worked fine but I had to import 604 qcf font in the application and Adjust the dimensions of each page>

[This is and image of the "Quran for Android" application it depends on ayahinfo_1260.db and the image for every page of the quran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfkwr.png)

[This is and image of my app using Flutter. I used here the qcf font in rich text and text span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyQQH.jpg)

[But as i told you I have to Adjust the dimensions of each page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brb9F.jpg)

There is a simple code for how I use qcf font

```dart
RichText(
  maxLines: 15,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      for (element in controller.quranV2) ...[
        if (element.v1Page == 3)
          TextSpan(
            text: element.codeV1.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'UthmanTN1', fontSize: 23),
          ),
      ]
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Are you using Canvas with CustomPainter?